# How do you import an R module to a computer with no internet?

Tags: r, installation, gephi

I'm working on a mac computer that has restricted-use data and cannot be connected to the internet. I need an R-module on the computer called rgexf. When I try to install it on R following the instructions [here](https://bitbucket.org/gvegayon/rgexf/wiki/Installation):

```
> install.packages('[where the zip file is]/rgexf_0.12.03.tar.gz', repos = NULL)
```

I get this error:

```
Installing package(s) into '/Users/samfinegold/Library/R/2.15/library' (as 'lib' is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository NULL/bin/macosx/leopard/contrib/2.15
Warning message: package '/Users/samfinegold/Desktop/rgexf_0.13.01.tar.gz' is not available (for R version 2.15.3)
```

I don't understand why the package wouldn't be available for the most recent version of R though.

Comment: You can try from the command line: `R CMD INSTALL rgexf_0.12.03.tar.gz`, in the directory containing the file.

Comment: You have a machine that is not allowed internet access but you're allowed to bring random files in on USB drives?  Someone in "IT" is unclear on the concept here!

Answer (score 5):

You have specified a source package (identified by the "tar.gz" extension) but not told `install.packages` to use `type ="source"`. You are also asking for the most recent version of the file which might be mated to version 3.0.0 for R.Its DESCRIPTION file says it does require compilation so you either need properly set-up tools for building source packages (if you want to install from source), or you need an appropriate binary version of the package. Whether there is an earlier version that can be mated to R 2.15.3 is an open question.

If you want to compile packages from source, you must have [the correct XCode for the version of OSX](https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/) that is on your machine. And you may need to get [additional development tools from the ATT.research website](http://r.research.att.com/). And if you have a more recent version of Xcode (higher than 3.x I think), don't forget to install the Command Line Tools package either from the Apple Developer Store or using the drop-down menu in a running installation of Xcode.

There is a [MacOS binary](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/contrib/r-release/rgexf_0.13.03.tgz) at CRAN. Given your difficulties with source installation I would try to get a copy of that on a USB stick and retry with a binary distribution. (You do not need to use `type="mac.binary"` since that is the default for that parameter to `install.packages`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the permissions on the computer? The first warning message looks like it could be a root/admin vs. user issue for accessing the file. The other possibility since you have a NULL in the warning message is that you've entered the directory wrong (try without the '/' to lead perhaps).

Comment: I see what you mean about how it could be a permissions issue. I've read a couple links but I'm unclear what permissions I should be changing. Is the "permissions" window I'm looking for in the R directory?

Comment: No, this is likely something with the computer itself. I assume this is a Linux server or something?

Comment: Clearly this is an older version of OSX. I'm not sure Apple is any longer distributing XCode for this version so going with the source compile of R packages may not be wise route for this user.

Comment: @TommyLevi I don't think that was the issue.